# Rate Times Distance Problem with Averages

Tags: average

On your drive to Hoover Dam, you maintain an average speed of 50 miles per hour on the way up. Returning home, you are only able to average 45 miles per hour because of heavy traffic. What is your average speed for the entire round trip?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

**Hints**

Average speed is $\frac{\text{total distance}}{\text{total time}}$. Assume the distance there is $d$. What is the distance back? What is the total distance?

Can you compute the time there and the time back?